# PHP & XML: How do I compare the text content of two XML Elements?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to write a script that goes through three existing XML documents and compiles a fourth XML document that contains all of the morphemes (linguist-speak for parts of words) in the existing three. I am trying to make sure this new morpheme database does not contain any duplicates, and I am having trouble getting it to not add duplicates. I will post the relevant snippet immediately below, and the entire chunk of relevant code at the bottom.

The check for duplicates is as follows: `((string)$source == (string)$storySource)`, where $source and $storySource are both simpleXMLElements like this: `<m>text</m>`. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Best,
Jimmy

Here is the entire loop for going through one of the XML files.

```
$storycorpus = new SimpleXMLElement($file,null,true);
$storyEntries = $storycorpus->xpath("//morpheme");
foreach($storyEntries as $entry){
    // check to see if in morpheme database. we will match the Pomo and the English, hence, if either is not a match,
    // we will add a new morpheme
    $storySource = $entry->m;
    $storyGloss = $entry->g;
    // set a variable equal to false
    $foundInDB = false; 

    //we will loop through the database looking for a match.    
    foreach($morphemeEntries as $existingMorpheme){
        $source = $existingMorpheme->source;
        $gloss = $existingMorpheme->gloss;

        // if we find a match, we will set our variable to be true and break out of the morpheme DB loop
        if(((string)$source == (string)$storySource) && ((string)$gloss == (string)$storyGloss)){
            $foundInDB = true; // problem: this line isn't firing
            break;
        }
    }
    // after the morphemeDB loop, we will check to see if the var is true. 
    if($foundInDB == true){
        // if it is true, we don't need to enter anything and can 
        // go to the next entry
        continue;
    } else{
        // if we didn't find a match, create a new morpheme
        $newMorphemeEntry = $morphemeDB->addChild("morpheme");
        $newMorphemeEntry->addChild("source", $storySource);
        $newMorphemeEntry->addChild("gloss", $storyGloss);
        $newMorphemeEntry->addChild("root", $storySource);
        $newMorphemeEntry->addChild("hypernym", $storySource);
        $newMorphemeEntry->addChild("link", "S");
        if(substr($storySource, 0, 1) == "-"){
            $newMorphemeEntry->addChild("affix", "suffix");
        } elseif(substr($storySource, -1, 1) == "-"){
            $newMorphemeEntry->addChild("affix", "prefix");
        } else{
            $newMorphemeEntry->addChild("affix", "root");
        }
    }
}
```

Okay, so I rewrote the block and used DOMDocument instead of SimpleXML, and I still am not having any luck in prevent duplicates. Here is the new code

```
    // check to see if in morpheme database. we will match the Pomo and the English, hence, if either is not a match,
    // we will add a new morpheme
    $phraseSource = $entry->nodeValue;
    $phraseGlossId = $entry->getAttribute("id");
    $phraseGloss = $xpath2->query("//g[@id =\"$phraseGlossId\"]")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    // set a variable equal to false
    $foundInDB = false; 

    //we will loop through the database looking for a match.    
    foreach($morphemeEntries as $existingMorpheme){
        $source = $existingMorpheme->getElementsByTagName("source")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $gloss = $existingMorpheme->getElementsByTagName("gloss")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        // if we find a match, we will set our variable to be true and break out of the morpheme DB loop
        if(($source == $phraseSource) && ($gloss == $phraseGloss)){
            $foundInDB = true; // problem: this line isn't firing
            break;
        }
    }
    // after the morphemeDB loop, we will check to see if the var is true. 
    if($foundInDB == true){
        // if it is true, we don't need to enter anything and can 
        // go to the next entry
        continue;
    } else{
        // if we didn't find a match, create a new morpheme
        $newMorphemeEntry = $morphemeXmlDoc->createElement("morpheme");

        $newMorphemeSource = $morphemeXmlDoc->createElement("source");
        $newMorphemeSource->nodeValue = $phraseSource;
        $newMorphemeEntry->appendChild($newMorphemeSource);

        $newMorphemeGloss = $morphemeXmlDoc->createElement("gloss");
        $newMorphemeGloss->nodeValue = $phraseGloss;
        $newMorphemeEntry->appendChild($newMorphemeGloss);

        $newMorphemeRoot = $morphemeXmlDoc->createElement("root");
        $newMorphemeRoot->nodeValue = $phraseSource;
        $newMorphemeEntry->appendChild($newMorphemeRoot);

        $newMorphemeHypernym = $morphemeXmlDoc->createElement("hypernym");
        $newMorphemeHypernym->nodeValue = $phraseSource;
        $newMorphemeEntry->appendChild($newMorphemeHypernym);

        $newMorphemeLink = $morphemeXmlDoc->createElement("link");
        $newMorphemeLink->nodeValue = "P";
        $newMorphemeEntry->appendChild($newMorphemeLink);

        $newMorphemeAffix = $morphemeXmlDoc->createElement("affix");
        $newMorphemeAffix->nodeValue = $phraseGloss;

        if(substr($phraseSource, 0, 1) == "-"){
            $newMorphemeAffix->nodeValue = "suffix";
        } elseif(substr($phraseSource, -1, 1) == "-"){
            $newMorphemeAffix->nodeValue = "prefix";
        } else{
            $newMorphemeAffix->nodeValue = "root";
        }
        $newMorphemeEntry->appendChild($newMorphemeAffix);

        $morphemeRootNode->appendChild($newMorphemeEntry);
    }
}
```

Here is what the script is searching through to create the new XML sheet:

```
<phrasicon>
<phrase id="4">
    <ref1>ES</ref1>
    <source>t̪o: xa jo: k'ala:</source>
    <morpheme>
      <m id="4.1">t̪o:</m>
      <m id="4.2">xa</m>
      <m id="4.3">jo:</m>
      <m id="4.4">k'ala:</m>
    </morpheme>
    <gloss lang="en">
      <g id="4.1">me</g>
      <g id="4.2">water</g>
      <g id="4.3">for</g>
      <g id="4.4">die</g>
    </gloss>
    <translation lang="en">I'm dying for water.</translation>
    <media1 mimeType="audio/wav" url="im_dying_for_water.wav"/>
    <ref2/>
    <media2 mimeType="" url=""/>
    <ref3/>
    <media3 mimeType="" url=""/>
  </phrase>
</phrasicon>
```

Here is what the new morpheme XML sheet ought to look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<morphemedatabase>
<morpheme>
  <source>t̪o:</source>
  <gloss>me</gloss>
  <root>t̪o:</root>
  <hypernym>t̪o:</hypernym>
  <link>P</link>
  <affix>root</affix>
</morpheme>
</morphemedatabase>
```

Comment: I thoroughly recommend you stop using simple xml and start using DOMDocument. Far better to work with

Comment: Hi Delboy, thanks for your feedback! This project already had a lot of PHP code that used simple xml, so for me and for the other developer I work with, using DOMDocument in some places and simple xml in others was going to lead to trouble. That, and I find DOMDocument to be a bit clunky for these things. That being said, I'll try to use DOMDocument here and see what happens. Thanks again!

Comment: Good luck and if you get stuck with DOM classes update your question, we'll try to help
!

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate that! As a general principle going forward, do you think it would be worth our time to rewrite all of our code that utilizes simple xml? Or should we just write everything from now on using DOMDocument and leave our simplexml code in place until we have to edit it in the future for other reasons?

Comment: If it works, no, only if you really need to! For new stuff, absolutely!

Comment: Could you add small examples of your XMLs to the question?

Comment: Okay, I added some of the XML code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that `$morphemeEntries` is a fixed list of `SimpleXMLElement` objects and will not get updated with the added nodes. I suggest using the `$morphemeDB` object for the check. Additionally you can replace the loop with an Xpath expression.

```
$storySource = $entry->m;
$storyGloss = $entry->g;

$foundInDB = count(
  $morphemeDB->xpath(
    sprintf('.//morpheme[source="%s" and gloss="%s"]', $storySource, $storyGloss)
  )
) > 0;
```

In DOM the same is possible with `DOMXpath::evaluate()`:

```
$phraseSource = $xpathSource->evaluate('string(m)', $entry);
$phraseGloss = $xpathSource->evaluate('string(g)', $entry);

$foundInDB = $xpathTarget->evaluate(
  sprintf(
    'count(//morpheme[source="%s" and gloss="%s"]) > 0', 
    $storySource, 
    $storyGloss
  )
);
```

In the DOM implementation you can nest `createElement()` into `appendChild()`, but you should add the content as text nodes (for proper escaping):

```
$newMorphemeEntry = $morphemeRootNode->appendChild(
  $morphemeXmlDoc->createElement("morpheme")
);
$newMorphemeEntry
  ->appendChild($morphemeXmlDoc->createElement("source"))
  ->appendChild($morphemeXmlDoc->createTextNode($phraseSource));
$newMorphemeEntry
  ->appendChild($morphemeXmlDoc->createElement("gloss"))
  ->appendChild($morphemeXmlDoc->createTextNode($phraseGloss));
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to cast to (string) before comparison.
call `->asXML()` method on each element instead.
substitute this:

```
if(((string)$source == (string)$storySource) && ((string)$gloss == (string)$storyGloss))
```

with this:

```
if(($source->asXML() == $storySource->asXML()) && ($gloss->asXML() == $storyGloss->asXML()))
```

or to compare the contained string (excluding the tags)

```
if(($source->__toString() == $storySource->__toString()) && ($gloss->__toString() == $storyGloss->__toString()))
```

The problem is that a SimpleXMLElement is not a "classic" PHP object. 
SimpleXML is built with "live" API linked to an internal representation of an XML document.

The manual page on [Comparing Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php) says "Two object instances are equal if they have the same attributes and values, and are instances of the same class."

in print_r() or var_dump() on a SimpleXMLElement appears as properties representing the child nodes and attributes. However, the actual implementation contains only a pointer into a memory structure created when the XML was parsed, which will be different even if you parse the same string twice. Thus simply comparing two SimpleXMLElement objects with == will never return true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Won't ->asXML() compare the entire XML elements, including the tags? My issue is that I'm trying to compare the text contents of two elements that probably look like <source>text1</source> and <m id=7>text2</m>. Hence, comparing the XML wouldn't help me. Although, I could probably figure out a way to trim off the tags after using ->asXML().

Comment: you can use ->__toString()

Comment: I could, but then I'd have to come up with a way to cut the XML tags off of the string. I'm just going to take delboy1978uk's advice and rewrite it using DOMDocument instead of SimpleXML. Anyway, mille grazie, da un italiano ad un altro!